# HTML form submit automated email using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have created an HTML form, without any difficulty (I am relatively new to HTML and CSS but comfortable with them). The problem is that I want the submit button to send the data inputted in the form by the user to my email address.

My PHP knowledge is **almost non-existent**, and I am totally stuck. If anyone has the patience to help, it would be most appreciated.

Here is the code for the form...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Life Academy | Pre-course questionnaire</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pcq.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,400,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="formbg">
    <div id="formcontent">
        <img src="pcqlogo.png" class="logo">
        <p><strong>Retirement Planning Course<br>Anonymous Pre-course Questionnaire</strong><br>So that the course may more accurately reflect your interests and possible concerns, we would like you to complete and return this questionnaire before the start of the course, by email, to<br> <a href="mailto:info@life-academy.co.uk"><strong>info@life-academy.co.uk</strong>.</a></p>
        <form>
            Age<br> <input type="text" name="age"><br>
            Years with present/last company<br> <input type="text" name="yearswithcompany"><br>
            Leaving Date<br> <input type="text" name="leavingdate"><br>
            Job Role<br> <input type="text" name="role"><br>

            Do you have a company or occupational pension plan?<br>
            <input id="yes" type="radio" name="companypension" value="yes">
            <label for="yes">Yes</label>
            <input id="no" type="radio" name="companypension" value="no">
            <label for="no">No</label><br>

            Do you have a personal &#40private&#41 pension plan?<br>
            <input id="yes" type="radio" name="personalpension" value="yes">
            <label for="yes">Yes</label>
            <input id="no" type="radio" name="personalpension" value="no">
            <label for="no">No</label><br>

            What would you like to gain from this course? Please describe in detail.<br> <textarea name="liketogain" class="largetextbox"></textarea><br>
            What are your main activities outside of work?<br> <input type="text" name="activities"><br>
            How do you think these activities will develop/change in the near future?<br> <textarea name="activitiesdevelop" class="largetextbox"></textarea><br>
            Have you any concerns about the future? If so, list them here:<br> <textarea name="futureconcerns" class="largetextbox"></textarea><br>
            Do you want to make changes to your health/lifestyle? If so, please describe the changes.<br> <textarea name="healthlifestylechanges" class="largetextbox"></textarea><br>
            How would you like the emphasis of your life to change in the future with respect to work/voluntary activity?<br> <textarea name="work" class="largetextbox"></textarea><br>
            Do you have any dietary requirements?<br> <input type="text" name="diet"><br>
            Do you have any other special requirements?<br> <textarea name="special" class="largetextbox"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" value"submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: ...in other words, you're looking for a PHP handler to send mail, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Make yourself a PHP submission page and set your form to POST to it:

```
<form action="file_name.php" method="POST">
//form fields go here
</form>
```

Then you'll need a PHP mail class. I recommend PHPMailer.
Basic Usage and download: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

A file like this:
**PHP_mailer.php**

```
<?php 
include 'mailer';
include 'library';
include 'files';
....rest of mailer code goes here....
?>
```

On the PHP mail page you can access any of the set fields with `$_POST['name of field goes here']`. So ex. `$_POST['name']` or `$_POST['age']`.

Note that this is a very basic explanation and will require extra steps like form validation, most likely using Javascript, and it will require some setup on your part of how you want email formatted, etc. Best option is to try and test it yourself until you can get it to work. There is also plenty of PHP documentation available if something is hard to grasp.